# How to fix the ag-grid header if table is auto height?

Tags: ag-grid

Ag-grid has nice documentation about grid auto-height: 
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/

But I can't understand how to make the ag-header fixed in the case when my table height is bigger than the viewport height. I scroll down through the table but header stays in the top.

You can see the same case when you choose 50 rows auto-height in the last example of the documentation page.

How to fix header in that case?

Comment: Sorry I removed my answer, I think I've misunderstood the question, do you wish to not see the header once you scroll down or are you trying to see the header? You should easily change the domLayout to be fixed or autoHeight to get your case, from there the header will change its view behavior. Could you create a codepen or some sort of small demo to see what problem you're witnessing specifically?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I'll try your solution. If it does not work I'll add a codepen than.

Answer (score 0):

Add the css below to have fixed header in ag grid with auto height.

**CSS**

```
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-header {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: auto;
    display: table;
    z-index: 99;
}
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-root-wrapper {
     border: none!important; 
}
```

Refer the code attached : [Auto Height - Fixed Header](https://plnkr.co/edit/TMNwMGeGaRglbPLe)